# adehabitatHR home range estimation is too small

Tags: epsg, adehabitathr

I have lat/long data of two animals tracked in Western Australia and I'd like to find their home ranges using adehabitatHR.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(sf)

quolls<-read.csv("quolls.csv")
head(quolls)
```

Latitude Longitude animal_ID
1 -22.62271  117.1247         1
2 -22.62286  117.1246         1
3 -22.62192  117.1223         1
4 -22.62021  117.1224         1
5 -22.61989  117.1244         1
6 -22.62022  117.1260         1

But the home range estimates of each animal are obviously too small.
I think the EPSG must be wrong but after a very long time looking I still can't find the right one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
# make a SpatialPoints dataframe without a CRS
quolls2 <- quolls
quoll.latlong<-data.frame(x=quolls2$Longitude,y=quolls2$Latitude)
coordinates(quolls2) <- quoll.latlong

# add crs
proj4string(quolls2) <- CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:4283")

mcp<-mcp(quolls2[,7],percent=95,unout = c("ha")) 
mcp
```

Home range for animal 1 is 1.217428e-08 and animal 2 is 6.253689e-08.

And likewise with kernel density estimation;

```
quoll_ud <- adehabitatHR::kernelUD(quolls2[7],grid = 450)
quoll_hr <- adehabitatHR::getverticeshr(quoll_ud, 99)
print(quoll_hr)
```

which estimates animal 1 at  2.36917592701502e-08 and animal 2 at 1.16018636413173e-07.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across the answer.. it's EPSG 28350.

I got it to work in the end by abandoning the raw lats and longs and instead importing a shapefile I had of the animal data with st_read.
Then st_transform to 28350.
Then as mcp accepts only SpatialPoints, I converted the object with
`as(obj, "Spatial")`.